# Can i use index.jsp instead of index.html in angular dist folder

Tags: angular, jsp, angular6, frontend

I have already an application build in `JSP` and there are some logics written in jsp file that is not possible in angular.

> I want to use the same file for angular i:e index.jsp instead of
>   index.html.

**How can i use it or any configuration needed to use it ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using angular cli you will see angular.json file. You will see we can change the default template for our angular app like this

```
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "progress": true,
        "extractCss": true,
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html" // change to your jsp file
    }
```

Please let me know if you have any problem